# How can I influence the stopping condition of a Bayesian Optimization with Facebook's Ax (BoTorch)?

Tags: python, facebook, bayesian

I am using Ax for Bayesian Optimization (BO). I am having a model with 5 integer parameters, and BO seems to find good solutions most of the time. However, in some cases BO stops very early with a suboptimal (far from optimum) solution. When ask for a new point with

`parameters, trial_index = ax.get_next_trial()`

it will always give me the last point over and over again. No new points are generated.

I know this must have something to do with the EI acquisition function. Maybe it doesn't exploit enough? How could I change the balance between exploration and exploitation?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Niolas